# Is there a way to automate the replacement of old fields with new fields of another database in Power BI?

Tags: database, powerbi, visualization

I have a situation in power BI that I want suggestions for doing it in an optimal way.

I've inserted a database with 50 tables in Power Bi and I made a lot of visualizations for each table, and now I want to insert a new database with same tables but different data in same visuals, and I need a really quick way to do that without needing to insert every fields in same visuals again.

Is there any way for power Bi to understand same fields in two tables and replaces them with each other automatically?

I tried a typical way, and I took a copy of previous file with all visualizations and I imported my new database and tried to replace every fields in previous tables with new ones,
and it was super exhausting and time-consuming.
because I have a lot more databases like that and I need to insert them in same visuals, I need HELP.

Comment: If you have the same table structure like table_name, column_name, and data_type same in both databases, I would suggest appending data together. For example table "tbl_sales" with data from "database_1" and "database_2". Just add an extra column like "data_source" which will contain values "db_1" and "db_2". Now if you add a slicer in the report with column "data_soure". So you can chose your desired database name from the filter and your visuals will show data from respected database/tables.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but one of my databases is specific for a City and all data and visuals are related to that specific City, and my another database is related to a different city . at first i took a copy from first BI file and I need a way to import my new tables and replace all the same fields and data , and after that remove the first database cause it was a copy and i don't need them anymore.

Comment: Probably modifying the M code of the queries (and optionally adding a step to rename the new columns to be named the same way as the old ones) in Advanced editor will be the fastest way to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-query-overview#advanced-editor

Comment: Make a new column for the city name, and then just have your reports filter the appended table by that column, assuming the other fields are the same per city.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer:

In PowerQuery, add a column to each table for the city.

```
Table.AddColumn( Source, "city", each "...", type text )
```

Then append all of the tables together.

```
Table.Combine( { table_city_1, table_city_2, ... } )
```

To maintain dataset integrity, you'll want to do this under your original table so all visuals will be redirected to it. E.g., if your original table was named "data_table", copy its code to a new query, and then put the combine step in the "data_table" query. Then you will only have to add filters to visuals/reports/pages as applicable to toggle between cities.